# Rotating y axis labels with mosaic plots WITHOUT overlap

Tags: r, plot, mosaic-plot, r-mosaic

This question is extremely similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492061/rotating-y-axis-labels-with-mosaic-plots) yet from another point of view which has not been responded.
Following the proposed code, I am able to generate mosaic plots and rotate the labels so that they are legible. The problem comes when (it seems) the `mosaic()` function from `vcd` package does not recognise the rotation and so it does not adapt the graph to fit the labels, yielding results like the following:

[image: mosaic graph]

Is there any way to change the margins between the labels and the titles? I would be surprised if I am the first one that has encountered this issue. I am open to using other packages to get mosaic graphs if applicable as well.

**Code**

```
aux = structure(c(0L, 0L, 3L, 46L, 107L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
9L, 0L, 23L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 14L, 1L, 8L, 26L, 6L, 11L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 29L, 10L, 62L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Dim = c(3L, 
13L), .Dimnames = list(abcdefghi = c("Madrid", "Valencia", "Granada"
), jklmnopqr = c("roknbjftxcwl", "mfchldbxuyig", "gtyoxeduijpw", 
"akbcefymvsiw", "ucbfxplietqk", "mzeykauprfdh", "piermgawyjht", 
"chjvatqbylxo", "merhcogjflbd", "wiyrugvmhjlq", "glszdqmjhkov", 
"giowaxrtsknm", "pxucytzvljqw")), class = "table")

library(vcd)
colours = c("brown","darkgreen","darkgrey","orange","darkred","gold","blue","red",
            "white","pink","purple","navy","lightblue","green","peachpuff","violet","yellow","yellow4")
aux_names = names(attr(aux,"dimnames"))
mosaic(aux,main=paste(aux_names,collapse=" vs. "),
       gp=gpar(fill=matrix(sample(colours,max(nrow(aux),ncol(aux))),1,max(nrow(aux),ncol(aux)))),
       pop = FALSE,labeling = labeling_border(rot_labels=c(90,0,0,0),
                                              just_labels=c("left","right")))
```

Comment: Are you using the `mosaic` function from the `vcd` package?

Comment: @KoenV yes I am

Comment: I get an error executing your code. After the call to `mosaic`: "Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :   cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'"

Comment: @KoenV my bad, forgot one line of code. should be working now.

Comment: edited yet again, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should do what i think you're after.

```
mosaic(aux,main=paste(aux_names,collapse=" vs. "),
       gp=gpar(fill=matrix(sample(colours,max(nrow(aux),ncol(aux))),1,max(nrow(aux),ncol(aux)))),
       pop = FALSE,labeling = labeling_border(rot_labels=c(90,0,0,0),
                                              just_labels=c("left","right"),
                                              offset_varnames = c(8,8,8,8)),
       margins = c(10, 10, 10, 10))
```

[image: margin plot]

Comment: Vcd functions plot using `strucplot`, further documentation can be found here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vcd/vcd.pdf